# How to set up Rails build on Cloudbees?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

I am trying to set up a Rails job on Cloudbees and I'm running into problems that I can't solve anymore. I tried to follow the instructions but didn't find enough details to find out what's wrong myself.

This is how the Shell execution section of my job currently looks like:

```
curl -s -o use-ruby https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/ruby/use-ruby
RUBY_VERSION=1.9.3-p327 source ./use-ruby
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
bundle exec rake db:test:create
bundle exec rake test
```

I'm actually not sure yet about the last 2 lines, since I never made it past line #3 ;)

When I run this, I get the following result:

```
(...)
Commencing build of Revision 2e1549004e2b49903d4d006ad8bfa7e4b4bfda08 (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 2e1549004e2b49903d4d006ad8bfa7e4b4bfda08 (origin/master)
[API Continuous Testing] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4854632522106638677.sh
+ curl -s -o use-ruby https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/ruby/use-ruby
+ RUBY_VERSION=1.9.3-p327
+ source ./use-ruby
++ [[ -z 1.9.3-p327 ]]
++ ruby187='1.8.7-*'
++ [[ 1.9.3-p327 == 1.8.7-* ]]
++ '[' '!' -f /scratch/jenkins/use.sh ']'
++ . /scratch/jenkins/use.sh
++ mkdir -p /scratch/jenkins/ruby
+++ addon_architecture
+++ uname -m
++ ruby_name=ruby-1.9.3-p327-x86_64
++ '[' '!' -f /scratch/jenkins/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p327-x86_64.tar.bz2 ']'
++ '[' '!' -f /scratch/jenkins/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p327-x86_64/bin/ruby ']'
++ export PATH=/scratch/jenkins/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p327-x86_64/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.latest/bin:/opt/jdk/latest/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/latest/bin:/opt/ant/latest/bin:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/home/jenkins/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk.latest/bin
++ PATH=/scratch/jenkins/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p327-x86_64/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.latest/bin:/opt/jdk/latest/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/latest/bin:/opt/ant/latest/bin:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/home/jenkins/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk.latest/bin
++ unset GEM_PATH
++ unset GEM_HOME
++ unset BUNDLE_PATH
+ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
/tmp/hudson4854632522106638677.sh: line 5: bundle: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I assumed that after the Cloudbees installer is finished, "bundle" would be available for me to execute. Is that not right? Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler is not included by default as there are many versions (and some people prefer a newer / older / pre-release version).

In regards the following bcrypt issue, it's caused by spaces in the job name. I've renamed the job in question and it now passes.

I've also added the PostgreSQL installer so your full install now completes successfully.

You should refer to http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/PostgreSQL for more information on PostgreSQL configuration (preparing the users and databases).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much guys, great great great help! :) Looks like I still need to work through some issues in order to get this running and get value out of it for myself (includes some learning on my part as well) but I'm going to accept your answer since this seems to solve the problem I was originally dealing with :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to install bundler, as if it was a "normal" ruby installation:

```
gem install bundler
```

As the first thing (as it doesn't come with ruby itself)

(although I can see why a "use-ruby" script could be expected to do that - I will see if it can).

Comment: Oho, now that worked and got me one step further. Now one Gem failed to install: "Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension." This causes the build further down to fail. Any idea about this?

Comment: According to Google and StackOverflow one of the main reasons for this is that there's no Ruby "Dev" package installed. I tried to do some combinations along the lines of "apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev" or by modifying the name of the Cloudbees Ruby distribution, but it all didn't work. Any hint on this?